# Cut one word before delimiter - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, cut

How do I use `cut` to get one word before the delimiter? For example, I have the line below in `file.txt`:

> one two three four five: six seven

when I use the `cut` command below:

```
cat file.txt | cut -d ':' -f1
```

...then I get everything before the delimiter; i.e.:

> one two three four five

...but I only want to get "five"

I do not want to use `awk` or the position, because the file changes all the time and the position of "five" can be anywhere. The only thing fixed is that five will have a ":" delimiter.

Thanks!

Comment: Your reason for not wanting to use awk does not make sense.

Comment: `cut -d ':' -f1 file.txt | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev` would work if you really want to use cut, although it would be far easier using awk or sed

Comment: my file can change as I mentioned, for example, s='one five: two three four seven six' , so I don't want to use print $5 fixed.

Comment: Amandan, that works! and I learnt a new command "rev" :)

Comment: Wasn't me. I just said that awk is much more than `print $5`.

Comment: Got it thanks Amandan! I am quiet new to stack overflow, not sure how I can vote your answer, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure bash:

```
s='one two three four five: six seven'
w=${s%%:*}                 # cut off everything from the first colon
l=${w##* }                 # cut off everything until last space
echo $l
# => five
```

(If you have one colon in your file, `s=$(grep : file)` should set up your initial variable)

Comment: Why are you making loads of variables?

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９: Why are you having all those wide nines? :P (For a serious answer - clarity, I suppose. But if I was actually thinking about what I was doing, I would have named them `string`, `words`, `lastword` or something similar.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to use more that one field delimiter here, `awk` comes to rescue:

```
s='one two three four five: six seven'
awk -F '[: ]' '{print $5}' <<< "$s"
five
```

**EDIT:** If your field positions can change then try this `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/.*[[:blank:]]/, "", $1); print $1}' <<< "$s"
five
```

Here is a BASH one-liner to get this in a single command:

```
[[ $s =~ ([^: ]+): ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
five
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, my file can change as I mentioned, for example, s='one five: two three four seven six' , so I don't want to use print $5 fixed.

Comment: If your field positions can change then try my edited awk command.

Comment: You're welcome, also check my BASH one-liner which I think will suit your task.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to do something like this:

```sh
cat file.txt | while read line
do
  for word in $line
    do
      if [ `echo $word | grep ':$'` ] then;
        echo $word
      fi
    done
done
```

if it is a consistent structure (with different number of words in line), you can change the first line to:

```
cat file.txt | cut -d':' -f1 | while read line
do ...
```

and that way to avoid processing ':' at the right side of the delimeter

Answer (score -1):

Try

`echo "one two three four five: six seven" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | awk '{print $NF}'`

This will always print the last word before first `:` no matter what happens